# Set another Value if Not exist in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

```
SELECT subjects.name as name , grades.grade as grade,  concat(instructors.lastname, ", ", instructors.firstname , " ", left(instructors.middlename, 1),".") as instructor
    FROM subjects
    JOIN grades
    JOIN instructors
    WHERE grades.student_id = 1 AND subjects.id = grades.subject_id AND instructors.subject_id = subjects.id
```

Result is

```
English    Instructor    Grade
Math       Instructor    Grade
```

But What I wanted is to give "N/A" in subjects that has no instructors yet. Example

```
English    Instructor    Grade
Math       Instructor    Grade
Science    N/A           Grade
History    N/A           Grade
```

How I am going to set a condition in my mySQL so the result will look exactly in the above example?

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TRy this ::

USing a left join and a `ifnull`

```
SELECT subjects.name as name , grades.grade as grade,  ifnull(concat(instructors.lastname, ", ", instructors.firstname , " ", left(instructors.middlename, 1),"."),'N/A)' as instructor
    FROM subjects
    LEFT JOIN grades on subjects.id = grades.subject_id
    LEFT JOIN instructors on instructors.subject_id = subjects.id
    WHERE grades.student_id = 1
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE grades.student_id = 1 AND subjects.id = grades.subject_id AND instructors.' at line 5

Answer (score 1):

`LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` like so:

```
SELECT 
  s.name as name , 
  g.grade as grade,  
  IFNULL(concat(i.lastname, ", ", i.firstname, ...), 'N/A') as instructor
FROM subjects s
LEFT JOIN grades g ON g.subject_id = s.id 
LEFT JOIN instructors i ON g.subject_id = i.subject_id ;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d9c05/6)

**Note that:** The way you write `JOIN`s is not correct. There is no `ON` clause after the `JOIN` clause. You have to put the join condition after the `ON` clause.

Comment: But How i am going to make "Null" to "NA"?
Thanks

Comment: @arjay0601 - Use `IFNULL(concat(i.lastname, ", ", i.firstname, ...), 'N/A') as instructor` like what I did in my updates answer. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can `Left join` or `right join` instead of `join` or `inner join`. `Left Join` will show all data on left side and null on right side if no related data. So your query will become:

```
SELECT subjects.name as name , grades.grade as grade,  
isnull(concat(instructors.lastname, ", ", instructors.firstname , " ",
left(instructors.middlename, 1),"."), 'N/A') as instructor
FROM subjects
LEFT JOIN grades ON subjects.id = grades.subject_id 
LEFT JOIN instructors  ON instructors.subject_id = subjects.id
WHERE grades.student_id = 1
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE grades.student_id = 1 AND subjects.id = grades.subject_id AND instructors' at line 7

Comment: look at modified answer. I just copy your query and miss join condition (ON... keyword)